# Additional investment compound interest calculation

Tags: java

Hi I try to figure out this scenario,
invest 12k each year, anuual rate is 3.5%, total 10 years.
my code start getting incorrect calculation since second year.
is there any logic error to use this for loop?
the expect result should be 12.42/25.28/38.59 etc
but I got 12.42/26.16/55.10/116.05.....

```
    int year=10;
    double eachYearInvest = 12, 
           eachYearRevenue=0,
           rate=1.035;
    for(int i=1; i<=year; i++) {            
        eachYearRevenue = eachYearInvest*rate;
        System.out.println("at " + i + " year the total revenue are " + eachYearRevenue);
        eachYearInvest = (eachYearRevenue+eachYearInvest)*rate;         
    }
```

Comment: This is the formula: amountX = principal * (1.0 + rate)^yearX (X denotes a particular year)

Comment: You are multiplying the rate with your value twice a year. First here `eachYearInvest*rate` and then one more time here `(eachYearRevenue+eachYearInvest)*rate`. Logically that rate is payed out once per year, so multiplying it into your result twice should be a massive red flag for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying by the interest rate twice for each loop. Also, the revenue/invest calculation doesn't make sense.

If you're defining revenue as the amount made relative to the starting amount, then I assume this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int year = 10;
    final double startingAmount = 12.0;
    final double rate = 1.035;
    double amount = startingAmount;
    for(int i = 1; i <= year; i++) {
        amount *= rate;
        System.out.println("at " + i + " year the total revenue is " + (amount - startingAmount));
    }
}
```

which outputs this:

```
at 1 year the total revenue is 0.41999999999999815
at 2 year the total revenue is 0.8546999999999976
at 3 year the total revenue is 1.304614499999996
at 4 year the total revenue is 1.7702760074999944
at 5 year the total revenue is 2.252235667762493
at 6 year the total revenue is 2.7510639161341786
at 7 year the total revenue is 3.2673511531988737
at 8 year the total revenue is 3.801708443560834
at 9 year the total revenue is 4.3547682390854625
at 10 year the total revenue is 4.927185127453452
```

Answer (score 0):

> the expect result should be 12.42/25.28/38.59 etc

What you want based on your question is future value (Deposit plus interest).
You need to multiply the sum of `(eachYearInvest + cumulativeYearsFutureValue)` by the `rate`, then print.  To round up I added `.005` to the results.  This presumes an initial investment of 12K specified in thousands of dollars.

```
int year=10;
double eachYearInvest = 12, // in thousands
cumulativeYearsFutureValue = 0
rate=1.035;
for(int i=1; i<=year; i++) {            
    cumulativeYearsFutureValue = (eachYearInvest + cumulativeYearsFutureValue)*rate;
    System.out.printf("at " + i + " year the cumulative future value is %.2f%n", 
     cumulativeYearsFutureValue+.005);
}
```

prints

```
at 1 year the cumulative future value is 12.42
at 2 year the cumulative future value is 25.28
at 3 year the cumulative future value is 38.58
at 4 year the cumulative future value is 52.35
at 5 year the cumulative future value is 66.61
at 6 year the cumulative future value is 81.36
at 7 year the cumulative future value is 96.63
at 8 year the cumulative future value is 112.43
at 9 year the cumulative future value is 128.78
at 10 year the cumulative future value is 145.71
```

Comment: thank you, I get the point where my logic loop wrong

Comment: @Don You're welcome.  Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    int year = 10;
    double eachYearInvest = 12, eachYearRevenue = 0, rate = 1.035, eachYearIn = eachYearInvest;

    for (int i = 1; i <= year; i++) {
        eachYearRevenue = eachYearIn * rate;
        System.out.println("at " + i + " year the total revenue are " + eachYearRevenue);
        eachYearIn = eachYearRevenue + eachYearInvest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are investing $12k, shouldn't your principal be `12_000.0`?

Also, the number formatter supports currencies.

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class RevenueCalculator {
    private static final NumberFormat currencyFormatter;

    static {
        currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double revenue = calculateRevenue(12_000.0, 0.035, 10);
        System.out.printf("Final amount: %s", currencyFormatter.format(revenue));
    }

    public static double calculateRevenue(double principal, double rate, int years) {
        double revenue = principal;
        for (int year = 1; year <= years; year++) {
            revenue *= (1 + rate);
            System.out.printf("At %d year(s), the total revenue is: %s%n",
                    year, currencyFormatter.format(revenue - principal));
        }
        return revenue;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
At 1 year(s), the total revenue is: $420.00
At 2 year(s), the total revenue is: $854.70
At 3 year(s), the total revenue is: $1,304.61
At 4 year(s), the total revenue is: $1,770.28
At 5 year(s), the total revenue is: $2,252.24
At 6 year(s), the total revenue is: $2,751.06
At 7 year(s), the total revenue is: $3,267.35
At 8 year(s), the total revenue is: $3,801.71
At 9 year(s), the total revenue is: $4,354.77
At 10 year(s), the total revenue is: $4,927.19
Final amount: $16,927.19
```

See also: https://www.calculateme.com/compound-interest/12000/3.5/10

Answer (score 0):

The *eachYearRevenue* assignment should include the previous year's value.

```java
eachYearRevenue = (eachYearInvest+eachYearRevenue)*rate;
```

As opposed to incrementing the *eachYearInvest* value.

```java
eachYearInvest = (eachYearRevenue+eachYearInvest)*rate;
```

So, your total code would be the following.

```java
int year=10;
double eachYearInvest = 12,
    eachYearRevenue=0,
    rate=1.035;
for(int i=1; i<=year; i++) {
    eachYearRevenue = (eachYearInvest+eachYearRevenue)*rate;
    System.out.println("at " + i + " year the total revenue are " + eachYearRevenue);
}
```

Output

```
at 1 year the total revenue are 12.419999999999998
at 2 year the total revenue are 25.274699999999996
at 3 year the total revenue are 38.579314499999995
at 4 year the total revenue are 52.34959050749999
at 5 year the total revenue are 66.60182617526247
at 6 year the total revenue are 81.35289009139666
at 7 year the total revenue are 96.62024124459553
at 8 year the total revenue are 112.42194968815637
at 9 year the total revenue are 128.77671792724183
at 10 year the total revenue are 145.70390305469527
```